# Running cron job from K8S cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I need to run a third part API in schedulded interval from k8s cluster. I have tried with k8s corn job but its not working getting error as invalid command . I am using below script. Can anyone suggest how to use it

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: corn-job
  namespace: scheduler
spec:
  schedule: "5 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c curl http://google.com
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: Outside of Kubernetes, try running `docker run busybox /bin/sh '-c curl http://google.com'`, which matches what you've written here.  Try iterating on that command line until it works, and translating the result back into Kubernetes syntax; one command-line argument per list item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

busybox image doesnt have curl binary. it wont work. use the below yaml or update the image

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: cron-demo
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: ekambaram/curl
            command: ["curl"]
            args: ["http://google.com"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

just tested it and find below the output

```
master $ kubectl get po
NAME                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
corn-job-1574850360-srwf6   0/1     Completed   0          44s

master $ kubectl logs -f corn-job-1574850360-srwf6
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
100   219  100   219    0     0     39      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--    54
```

Comment: Thanks Ekambaram , This is what I am looking for. Can you just help one more things how we can pass more arguments like header like -H "authorization:Basic OGSFJjNTAyhsgTBGSGRkZhdgTYA" , i mean how to use escape character.

Comment: open a new question with your requirement